# Reference object properties from with the structure

Tags: json, angular, typescript

In my Angular app, I have a object structure to hold my constant variables. As such:

```
MY_VARS: {
    DEFAULT: 'BLOTTER',
    SELECT_A_ROLE: '-- Select a role --'
},
```

I also have a separate object in this file which holds values that I use for my dropdowns. As Such:

```
ROLE_TYPES: [
  {"value": "DEFAULT", "text":"-- Select a role--"},
  {"value":"FOO", "text":"Foo"},
  {"value":"BAR", "text":"Bar"}
]
```

I want to be able to reference values in either `MY_VARS` or `ROLE_TYPES` as constants so I don't have to hard-code them. I have tried one suggestion to return as:

```
[{
  "value": function(){ return this.DEFAULT },
  "text": "-- Select a Role--"
}
```

And it compiles but the values are being returned empty.
Does anyone know a good way to reference these vars from within its own, or another object structure in the same file?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, "I want to be able to reference values in either MY_VARS or ROLE_TYPES as constants so I don't have to hard-code them." By definition, creating them as constants is hard coding them.

Comment: Ideally, I would "hard-code" into one variable, and reference that variable every time I need the value. Rather than hard-coding each instance to explicitly be 'BLOTTER' for example. 

So in the above example, I want ROLE_TYPES to be able to reference MY_VARS.DEFAULT. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you then trying to reference these directly in your template?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just are not accessing the variables you have set up.

If you have this:

```
MY_VARS: {
    DEFAULT: 'BLOTTER',
    SELECT_A_ROLE: '-- Select a role --'
},
```

Then it seems you just need to point at those variable names, not strings.

```
{
  "value": MY_VARS.DEFAULT,
  "text": MY_VARS.SELECT_A_ROLE
}
```

I can't be totally sure how to access them though since you didn't post the context of how these variables are stored.  Are they class properties, constants, etc?

For example, if these were all in a class:

```js
class myThing {
  MY_VARS = {
    DEFAULT: 'BLOTTER',
    SELECT_A_ROLE: '-- Select a role --'
  };

  ROLE_TYPES = [
    {"value": this.MY_VARS.DEFAULT, "text": this.MY_VARS.SELECT_A_ROLE},
    {"value":"FOO", "text":"Foo"},
    {"value":"BAR", "text":"Bar"}
  ]

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.ROLE_TYPES);
  }
}

//----
const x = new myThing();
```

You can run this code and see the output is as you expect it to be

---

### Editing based on comments below

Ok, so if you have this file named `my-constants.ts`

```
export const MY_VARS = {
  DEFAULT: 'BLOTTER',
  SELECT_A_ROLE: '-- Select a role --'
};
```

And then in another file you want to use those exported variables, you have to import them like this:

```
import { MY_VARS } from '../path/to/my-constants';

export class Example {
  ROLE_TYPES = [
    {"value": MY_VARS.DEFAULT, "text": MY_VARS.SELECT_A_ROLE},
    {"value":"FOO", "text":"Foo"},
    {"value":"BAR", "text":"Bar"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes. So the structure is as such. 
In my constants.ts file, I just have 

export const Constants = {
VAR1:"FOO", 
VAR2:"BAR",
VAR_COLLECTION_ONE{..}, 
VAR_COLLECTION_TWO{..}
}

So all of the variables I want to access are in VAR_COLLECTION_TWO. 
Using this.VAR_COLLECTION_TWO.VAR does not seem to register. Not finding "this" and the value is coming as blank.

Comment: You've posted incomplete code because I did not gather that at all from your original post.  It's hard to tell what is wrong without seeing the code or at least a somewhat reproducible example.  If you have a file that exports the vaiable, then you have to import it into your other file.  When you do that you won't be using `this` to access it since it's from another file, not the current class.  You only use `this` to refer to members on the same class you are on.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable.

Here is an example that is not Angular specific, but can easily be used inside an Angular component or service.

```js
const ROLE_TYPES = [
  {"key": "DEFAULT", "text":"-- Select a role--"},
  {"key": "FOO", "text":"Foo"},
  {"key": "BAR", "text":"Bar"}
]

const MY_VARS = {
  DEFAULT: 'BLOTTER',
  FOO: 'Something',
  BAR: 'Else',
  SELECT_A_ROLE: '-- Select a role --'
};

const dereferenced = ROLE_TYPES.map(r => ({...r, value: MY_VARS[r.key]}));

console.log(dereferenced);

// or if you want to dereference a single item
function getRoleByKey(key) {
  const role = ROLE_TYPES.filter(r => r.key = key)[0];

  return { ...role, value: MY_VARS[key]};
}

console.log(getRoleByKey('DEFAULT'));
```